How do make the tabview close on logout in flutter?
I'm creating an app in flutter and i added login to it, but while logout the home bar stays there while also showing the new login page.
So below is the code for logout
class profile extends StatelessWidget {
  profile({super.key});
  final _myBox = Hive.openBox("mybox");

  final loggedModel log = loggedModel();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          height:100,
          width: 100,
          child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: ()=> {
              log.out = true,
                Navigator.pop(context),
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute<void>(
                builder: (BuildContext context) => const Splash(),
              ),)
        },
              child: Text("LOGOUT")
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

so after login the it returns a widget of homescreen which has cupertinotabscaffold, and in that there's one page of profile containing the logout button. so when i logout the logout page is loaded but the cupertino tab stays there as shown in pics below
this is the main login page

and this is the profile with logout button

and here you can see that after logout the tab is still present and im not able to pop it out or remove it

i tried poping the homescreen or closing the app itself after logging out but they are not working
